# JSON array not sent in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have two pages; one of them written in Javascript and other purely PHP.

I try to send a JavaScript array and send it as JSON:

```
var myarr= new Array();
myarr["170864"]="mymail@corporate.com";
myarr["999900"]="escobar@pepes.es";


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "to_sent_mail.php",
    data: { envio:myarr },
    success: function() {
        alert('Enviado!');
    }
});
```

In the pages "to_sent_mail.php":

```
$array=$_POST['envio'];
foreach ($array as $codfactura => $lista)
{
    $lista_email=split(';',$lista);
    echo 'Mandando factura ' ."{$codfactura}" . '<br>';
    foreach ($lista_email as $direccion) {
        echo 'Direccion: ' . $direccion . '<br>';
    }
}
```

This array isn't sent as code execution doesn't enter foreach loop. 
I tried debugging XHR in Chrome but I cannot view the content of the request.

Comment: Add a picture of the network tab on your chrome developer tool and the console also when the request is made

Comment: `"And not enter foreach sentence"` How are you ascertaining that?

Comment: Thank you for the theme of array but now I have problem with foreach sentence. Not enter in it. Whats the problem?